# A function with class name

Tags: c++

Here is a code of a class of Linked List , i have a question on the function `Singly_linked_list *GetNext()`.What does that means if a class name is stated before the function name? Is that a data type?Also,same question on the data member `Singly_linked_list *nextPtr`.I Please help
Thank you

```
class Singly_linked_list // Use a class Singly_linked_list to represent an object{
public:
// constructor initialize the nextPtr
Singly_linked_list()
{
    nextPtr = 0; // point to null at the beginning
}

// get a number
int GetNum()
{
    return number;
}

// set a number
void SetNum(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

// get the next pointer
Singly_linked_list *GetNext()
{
    return nextPtr;
}

// set the next pointer
void SetNext(Singly_linked_list *ptr)
{
    nextPtr = ptr;
}

 private:
int number;
Singly_linked_list  *nextPtr;
 };
```

Comment: You really need an [introductory book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/179910). Those are the return type of the functions in question.

Comment: Nothing is being returned _to_ the class. What's being returned is an instance of the class (or a pointer to one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// get the next pointer
Singly_linked_list *GetNext()
{
    return nextPtr;
}
```

This means the function `GetNext` returns a pointer to an instance of the class `Singly_linked_list`.

Likewise

```
Singly_linked_list  *nextPtr;
```

means `nextPtr` is a pointer to an instance of the class `Singly_linked_list`.

Comment: Edit: understanding how something can be of the type of a class was the main problem in the question -- emphasized that